# How do I import javax.validation into my Java SE project?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, hibernate-validator, bean-validation

I'm trying to add constraints checking, as described here [How to specify the cardinality of a @OneToMany in EclipseLink/JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705759/how-to-specify-the-cardinality-of-a-onetomany-in-eclipselink-jpa)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are the dependencies I'm using (with Maven):

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Bean Validation API and RI -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

That you can get from this repository:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <name>JBoss repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: See the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17329473/642706) for latest [Bean Validation 1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/) version update.

Answer (score 24):

The dependencies as of 2019:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This transitively pulls in the dependency to the Bean Validation API, so you don't need to do this anymore:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

For additional features, Expression Language and CDI support, you might need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

*Source: [Hibernate Validator documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject)*

These are all in Maven Central Repo, so you don't need to add the JBoss repo.

And BTW here's my example convenience method:

```
public static <T extends Object> void  validate( T object ) throws MigrationException
{
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> valRes = validator.validate( object );
    if( ! valRes.isEmpty() )
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Validation failed for: ");
        if( object instanceof Origin.Wise )
            sb.append( ((Origin.Wise)object).getOrigin() );
        else
            sb.append(object);

        for( ConstraintViolation<T> fail : valRes)
        {
            sb.append("\n  ").append( fail.getMessage() );
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( sb.toString() );
    }
}
```

The `Origin.Wise` is something like JAXB's `@XmlLocation Locator`.

---

In 2013 (the original post) the versions were:

```
    <!-- BeanValidation and Hibernate Validator. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The URL is broken - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution other than `Hibernate`

### Overview

`javax.validation (validation-api)` is validation rules that follows `JSR 380 Java Bean Validation Specification`. The validation rules need a `validator` in order to perform validating according to the validation rules.

And there are various validators such as `hibernate` (the most popular one), `Bval`, etc.

## Bval

`Bval` is an alternative solution that I think It pretty cool also besides `Hibernate`. And here you can follow my alternative solution:

#### MVN

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
            <artifactId>bval-jsr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

#### Implementation

create static a validator

```
...

import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;

import org.apache.bval.jsr.ApacheValidationProvider;
...

private static final Validator validator;

static {
        validator = Validation.byProvider(ApacheValidationProvider.class).configure().buildValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator();
    }
```

There you go!!!.
Again, validator, it is just a validator, in which you switch to other validators easily.

## Pro&Con

It is not that popular, but You gonna like it.

Answer (score 0):

For Maven projects only is necessary use this dependency for validation annotations:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot you can add the following dependency

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```