# JSR-305 annotations replacement for Java 9

Tags: annotations, static-analysis, java-9, jsr305, java-platform-module-system

So far we have been using the Findbugs JSR-305 annotations (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305) and everything including tool support (Sonar, Eclipse, Findbugs, …) has been working fine.

However it is our understanding that Jigsaw in Java 9 is going to break JSR-305 annotations (one package in two modules is not allowed). This was confirmed at JavaOne 2015. Oracle's reasoning is JSR-305 never happened and JSR-250 would have to endorse these annotations.

We're looking for replacements for JSR-305 annotations that work in both Java 8 and Java 9. If history is any guide the time between Java 9 GA and Java 8 EOL will be rather short and we would like to fix any incompatibilities in our code in advance. In theory we could upgrade the annotations module of the JDK but doing this across our toolchain seems like a lot of work.

Comment: I asked a question recently going in the same direction ([futureproof @NonNull annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892063/which-nonnull-java-annotation-to-use)) however the question got quickly closed down. I still believe people are interested in the answer.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It’s true that two modules cannot, ordinarily, define types in the same
package.  Until recently, putting `jsr305.jar` on the class path of a
JDK 9 build would have no effect: That JAR file defines types in the
`javax.annotation` package but that package is defined in the platform’s built-in
`java.xml.ws.annotation` module, and the latter takes precedence.

Owing in part to the widespread use of `jsr305.jar`, however, and also to make
it easier for existing application servers to migrate to JDK 9, we changed
the default set of root modules to exclude the annotations module, among
others.  Putting `jsr305.jar` on the JDK 9 class path works out-of-the-box
with both JDK 9 and JDK 10; details are available in
[JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#EE-modules).  It will continue
to work out-of-the-box with later releases since the annotations module, along
with all the other Java EE and CORBA modules, were removed in JDK 11
per [JEP 320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).

Comment: Does this mean I can't use `@Nonnull` and `@PostConstruct` in the same project?

Comment: I guess you can craft a custom module with both `java.annotations.common` and `jsr305.jar` annotations if such need arise.