# The best way to handle or avoid NPE in java-8?

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception, java-8

How to avoid/handle more clear and safer `NullPointerException` in java-8 ?

But other than `Optional` class:

```
Optional emptyOptional = Optional.empty();

emptyOptional.ifPresent(System.out::println);

if (emptyOptional.isPresent())
     System.out.println(emptyOptional.get());
```

is there other way in `java-8` ?

Comment: Except for Optional, there's nothing more than the usual `== null` and `!= null` checks. Avoid nulls as much as possible. If you're really concerned about null-safety and are willing to, then use Kotlin, which has top-notch null-safety.

Comment: which IDEA you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

The only feature for avoiding `!= null` statement in java 8 is Optional, if you want to to use different patterns, you have few options:

1. [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
2. Annotation based, for example like [JetBrains @NotNull/@Nullable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html). for more details check [Java @NotNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)

Moreover you can check this answer in SOF about [avoiding-null-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)

Comment: There's also a newer list of null annotations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892063/which-nonnull-java-annotation-to-use . In that thread you'll find an answer by MErnst (spec lead of JSR 308) highlighting the significant difference between "old" declaration annotations and TYPE_USE annotations (Java 8) -- As the question is specifically mentions Java 8 it is worth noting that TYPE_USE annotations allow for much more complete analysis.